# Library for CSR Harmony (Bluetooth stack)

Tags: library, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to a smart watch usign the BLE Gatt profile.

I end up with a RT-BT4B Bluetooth dongle which required me to install the CSR_Harmony_2.1.63.0_fre_build_securitybased driver I found from the Rocketek website. (Otherwise my watch couldn't be found).

I'm a 32feet.net user and I found pretty quickly that I can't use it with my dongle. (Stack not supported exception).

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack#CSR_Harmony) CSR Harmony seem to be a bluetooth stack, so I tried to find any SDK but end up (in the best scenario) on a 404 pages.

From one random forum post I found CSR Harmony has been deprecated and CSR has been bought by Quadcomm. So this may explain some issue with my search I have.

I also tried to look for CSR Synergy BT library in hope it may work with CSR Harmony but couldn't find a download.

As a side question, i'm scary that the bluetooth dongle couln't even be able to use the Gatt profile because I can't find any reference to that.

Thanks

Comment: Whould be great to know your OS. Any way, any Bluetooth dongle can be used with any Bluetooth drivers. So if you run Windws 8 or 10 you can simple use Microsoft Bluetooth drivers that shipped with Windows. If you use Windows 7 or Vista (or even XP) you can try BlueSoleil Bluetooth drivers (it supports BLE on any Windows platforms). On Win 8 you may face some issues with your watch because it has very limited GATT support. So you may need BlueSoleil there as well. (In fact I do not know if 32feet supports BLE/GATT on something except Windows 10).

Comment: I don't know why you didn't post this as an answer but it seem to do the job (the driver work and 32feet can see my device as well).
Unfortunatly 32feet doesn't seem to support BLE at all... so I will try the BlueSoleil SDK as well.

If you post your comment as an answer I will set it as accepted

Comment: I checked 32feet site it it looks like 4.x supports BLE (probably on Win 10 only, not sure). You also can try [Bluetooth Framework](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). It supports BLE with BlueSoleil (starting from Win 7, requires BS 10) and Microsoft drivers (starting from Win 8).

Comment: For 32feet I found an article about supporting it on >= Win 8 (somehow I gave up right away without even trying anything.. #fail)
After looking at your comment I looked into the code and it does indeed have Gatt implementation. I will try !
Seriously, thanks !